# Google Analytics Reg Ex for Goals

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am relatively new to REGEX issues and am having a problem to validate some urls.

```
(\b/valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-\b[0-9])
```

Should validate following URLS as true

```
/valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-5s/
/valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-6/
/valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-xs/
/vendere-iphone-8-plus-usato-rotto/
```

Following URLs should be false:

```
/vendere/
/valutazione-riparare-vendere-smartphone/
/valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone/
```

Could somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: Try `/(?:valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-[0-9]|vendere-iphone)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.

`\/(valutazione-riparare-vendere-iphone-.*|vendere-iphone-.*)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I gonna try it out tomorrow and tell you!